# Can I use FLEX options for less than 100 shares?

Tags: stocks, options, flex-options

Suppose I own 25 shares of GOOGL (worth approximately $35,000 at the moment). I want to sell covered calls on these shares. I understand that traditional exchange-traded options are for 100 shares only, but I've recently discovered FLEX options. Can I use FLEX options to sell a covered call on 25 shares? If so, what is the procedure for entering into a FLEX options contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OCC publishes the [FLEX Options Product Specifications](https://www.theocc.com/clearing/clearing-services/specifications-flex-options.jsp). Although the expiration date, exercise style, strike price of FLEX options are variable, the *contract multiplier* does not appear to be flexible, so it would still be for 100 shares.  As a result, your position is of insufficient size to be able to write a covered call, unless google performs a *stock split*.